# Tensorflow v2.16 tf.keras.layers Embedding not accepting argument for input_length

Tags: python, tf.keras, keras-layer, embedding

While working with Embedding for an LSTM model I came across an issue with input_length:

ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to Embedding: {'input_length': 536}

Is input length being replaced with something else? Is this an error with the early release version or is the argument for the Embedding layer getting updated? How can I specify the input_length in the embedding layer for keras from tf 2.16?

It seems like python 3.12 does not have any other available tensorflow versions available, when trying to do pip install tensorflow=2.15.0 or any other version I get an error saying that pip can't find it. Should I adjust the python version on my machine or get Anaconda navigator to adjust it? Does it make it easy to work with different python version?

I tired installing another version of tensorflow to fix it but no other versions are available for python 3.12.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see the same issue with tensorflow 2.15.0 with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(24, 10, input_length=4))
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `input_length` with `input_shape`.